# Python Substitute nth Match from a Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, replace, substitution

I'm using the following regex:

```
(ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB)
```

To find these three words in the following sentence:

```
The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was unaffected by these events.
```

I'm trying to run a loop to get user inputs that will change either ADJECTIVE, NOUN or VERB:

```
new = ''
for c, item in enumerate(madlib_regexp.findall(text), 1):
    print(type(c))
    # get user input
    if item[0] == 'A':
        replace = input('Enter an ' + item.lower() + ': ')
    else:
        replace = input('Enter a ' + item.lower() + ': ')

    # replace matches with inputs
    global new
    new = madlib_regexp.sub(replace, text)
```

The biggest struggle I'm facing is using the "c" value in enumerate to solely substitute the c'th match for my loop. For example, "VERB" would be the 3rd match in my string, so I want the current user input to solely substitute the 3rd match.

Comment: The `nltk` library is best suited for this purpose as it is possible to tokenize words based on type such as Noun, Adjective etc..

Comment: I'm not trying to find adjectives or verbs. I'm trying to find the exact literal word "ADJECTIVE" in my string. Is the library able to do this?

Comment: Got it. what are the variables `new` and `text` for? I'm assuming `text` is the full text which will be modified as you've shown in the example. The `madlib_regexp` must be the regex expression. The regex does not seem to be valid?

Comment: The regex is valid I used r'(ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB)'. New is supposed to be the new text string with the replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extract the value you want to replace and use a new `re.sub` call to replace it:

```
import re
matches = madly_regexp.findall(text)
for c, item in enumerate(matches, 1):
    print(type(c))
    # get user input
    if item[0] == 'A':
        replace = input('Enter an ' + item.lower() + ': ')
    else:
        replace = input('Enter a ' + item.lower() + ': ')

    # replace matches with inputs
    text = re.sub(item, replace, text)
```